# sizeof operator changing during runtime?

Tags: c++, c

The `sizeof` operator is a compile time operator but in the program below it is changing at run time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func (int i) { 
    int a[i]; 
    printf("%d \n", sizeof(a)); 
} 

main() { 
    int i = 0; 
    while(i <= 5) { 
        func(i); 
        i++; 
    } 
}
```

memory will be allocated at runtime. how the compiler will calculate structure size with out structure padding?

Comment: Please post some syntactically valid code.

Comment: Is this program executing??

Comment: This code is neither valid C nor valid C++.

Comment: `int a[i];` is illegal in C++. Some compiler may offer it as an extension; you'd have to consult that compiler's documentation to find out what the consequences of using that array is.

Comment: @MattMcNabb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062621/difficulty-in-understanding-variable-length-arrays-in-c

Comment: VLAs are valid for C99 or later, but then C99 or later also disallows implicit `int`...yay?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Acording to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10062633/2507444) variable length arrays are valid in C99 or later (as T.C. stated)

Comment: @PeterClark C++ is not a "later" version of C99

Comment: Each time you call the function with different parameter,you are invoking the same array with different length. In C you cannot change the length of array once you declare it. So this is invalid code.

Comment: @shashank Not true. As already mentioned C99 and later allow variable length arrays so that part is completely valid (although the implicit int on main is dodgy).

Comment: This code _is_ invalid, but only (for C) the first call to `func` with `i` being 0. There are no zero-size objects in C.

Answer (score 6):

Your information is outdated. `a` is a variable-length array; for those, `sizeof` is determined at runtime. Variable-length arrays are a C99 feature that did not exist when the source of your information was written.

Comment: i think sizeof is a compile time operator. is it executed at run time? can u please tell me.main(){int a=10,b;b=sizeof(++a);printf("%d %d \n",a,b);}

Comment: The C standard doesn't distinguish "compile time" and "run time", that is a pedagogical distinction that is useful sometimes... when talking about `sizeof` since 1999, this is not one of those times :)  `sizeof` on an object gives you the number of bytes in that object , regardless of what sort of object it is.

Comment: @user3637903 `sizeof` is a compile time operator, but VLA is an exception (and the only exception) to that rule, i.e, `sizeof` is only not compile time operator when the operand is a VLA.

Answer (score 2):

[VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)-s are pretty much the only case where `sizeof` is not a compile time constant.

Answer (score 1):

`a[i]` in not legal in Standard C++, though it's supported as an extension by some compilers (e.g. [GCC documents it here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)) - such an extension might arrange whatever behaviour it likes for the `sizeof` operator, but would most sensibly base it on the C behaviour.

Comment: memory will be allocated at runtime. how the compiler will calculate structure size with out structure padding?

Comment: @user3637903 the compiler must include any padding, but to do so it simply needs to multiply `i` by the size of the array elements *rounded up if necessary to a multiple of the element's alignment*.  Put another way, `sizeof(a)` can be calculated as `sizeof(int[2])/2*i`, as the compile-time calculation of the size of `int[2]` must already factor in padding.  In your case `int` on the huge majority of systems has size 4, needs alignment of 4, so it's just `i * 4`.  Note it's runtime evaluated based on `i`, but not particularly hard to do.